# Issue with @preact/signals-react useSignal not triggering re-render across components

Tags: reactjs, signals, state-management, preact

I'm facing an issue with the @preact/signals-react library where a signal update in one component is not triggering a re-render in another component. Here's a simplified version of my code:

Store.tsx:

```
import { signal } from "@preact/signals-react";

interface DropedFileType {
  value?: {
    file_format?: string;
  };
}
export const DropedFile: DropedFileType = signal({});
```

ViewArea.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { useSignal } from "@preact/signals-react";
import { DropedFile } from "./Store";

function ViewArea() {
  const dropedFile = useSignal(DropedFile);

  return (
    <div>
      {dropedFile.value?.file_format === "3mf" && <h1>File format is 3mf</h1>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ViewArea;
```

In this setup, when DropedFile.value is updated in another component, the change is not reflected in ViewArea until a manual re-render is triggered (e.g., by clicking somewhere on the page).

Has anyone faced a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I tried using the `useSignal` hook from `@preact/signals-react` to track changes in a signal defined in a separate store file (`Store.tsx`). I was expecting that when the signal's value is updated in one component, it would trigger a re-render in another component (`ViewArea.tsx`) where the signal is being used. However, the re-render is not happening automatically. Instead, the updated value is only reflected when I manually trigger a re-render, for example, by clicking somewhere on the page.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't followed the setup instructions, [found here](https://github.com/preactjs/signals/tree/main/packages/react#react-integration). You must use the Babel plugin or the `useSignals()` hook, yet you're using neither.

```
// ViewArea.tsx
import React from "react";
import { useSignal } from "@preact/signals-react";
import { useSignals } from "@preact/signals-react/runtime";
import { DropedFile } from "./Store";

function ViewArea() {
  useSignals();
  const dropedFile = useSignal(DropedFile);

  return (
    <div>
      {dropedFile.value?.file_format === "3mf" && <h1>File format is 3mf</h1>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ViewArea;
```